# button OnClick event doesn't fire at the first time in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an issue on button OnClick event. 
There is a refresh button in a user control ("header") which will refresh a place holder ("phContent") that generates some other user controls at run time. However, the button OnClick event doesn't fire until the whole place holder content loads.

**Page.aspx**

```
<ext:ContentHeader ID="header" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upControl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phContent" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="header" EventName="OnFormSubmit" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**UserControl.ascx**

```
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="btnRefresh_OnClick" />
</div>
```

**UserControl.cs**

```
protected void btnRefresh_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some code

    OnFormSubmit(this, e);
}
public delegate void UserControlFormSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event UserControlFormSubmit OnFormSubmit;
```

Comment: if (OnFormSubmit != null)  OnFormSubmit(this, e);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly the page and source code is.

But from front-end, take for jQuery as example.

You can try something like:

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#btnRefresh').on('click',function(){
       //load the content by ajax
       jQuery('#phContent').load('#chart');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the button in updatepanel as well.

```
<ext:ContentHeader ID="header" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upControl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="btnRefresh_OnClick" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but the button is auto-generating from user control. cannot put it into update panel as a static way.